# FontAwesome icon not shown in CSS :after selector in Chrome?

Tags: css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

This is my HTML:

```
<hr class="star-light">
```

This is my CSS:

```
hr.star-light:after {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #EF672F;
}

hr.star-light:after, hr.star-primary:after {
    content: "\f005";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -.8em;
    padding: 0 .25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

It shows a hr with a white star in the middle in Firefox, but in Chrome its just a hr, no star is shown.

Any idea what I have to change in order to make it work in Chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this may help you.

Please try below CSS.

```
hr.star-light:after, hr.star-primary:after {
content: "\f005";
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
top: 0em;  /* changed value from -.8em to 0em */
padding: 0 .25em;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

Is there any reason to assigned negative value to top property?

Please see codepen example - https://codepen.io/prakashrajotiya/pen/ZEzxKdJ?editors=1100